# Using HTTPS cant't connect neo4j Browser to Neo4j Server

Tags: neo4j

I have a Windows 2019 Server, and I installed Neo4j community edition. In `neo4j.conf` file, I changed the configuration as per Neo4j Docs to access over HTTPS, but it is not working (the Browser is not opening). Whereas in HTTP the Browser is opening and connecting to the Neo4j Server.

How do I configure the server to properly access the browser and server over HTTPS? I followed the Neo4j Docs and some articles but didn't find any proper solution.

I added the SSL and changed the configuration file as per Neo4j Docs.
Are there any config or other changes that I missed? I was able to open the browser at `localhost:7474` and able to connect to `bolt://localhost:7687`, but not able to open in HTTPS after adding SSL in .Key and .Crt format as per docs.